# GPU fan turns off and display turns off

Tags: display, fan, overheating, gpu

My GPU fan turns off after running for some time and the display blacks out. After some investigation, I found that the GPU was too hot and probably got shut down for good but the same issue doesn't happen on Windows. Below is my PC's config:
AMD Ryzen 7 3800X 8 Core
GPU: Geforce RTX 2600
RAM: 16 GB Corsair Vengeance
Motherboard: Asrock